# How to get OpenLayers Plugin to render base maps at a large scale i.e. 1:1000 or larger?

Tags: rendering, qgis-openlayers-plugin, zoom, bing-maps

Am I the only one with this problem? You have a nice OpenLayers base map and get ready to digitize vegetation at a very high resolution but as soon as you zoom in, OpenLayers fails to render the base map! It's so frustrating. I've tried using GeopapaTile to create a cache that I can use directly from my hard drive but I can't figure out how to call the zoomed png files (if they are in fact higher resolution, I don't know) that make up the tile cache. I am only able to add the raster overview file that GeopapaTile gives with a tif extension and tfw but when I zoom in, I get pixels, not higher resolution.

I'm using Windows 10 QGIS 2.10.1 OpenLayers Plugin 1.3.6 and both Bing and Google Maps Aerial and Aerial Hybrids. There is another ticket that refers to this problem (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6822) Question followup "... I have similar issues with Bing aerial, only a bit more severe. In this case, Bing aerial does not display any imagery at all past a certain zoom point." Answer  that says: "The latest issues with Google Maps layers are fixed in the newly released OpenLayers Plugin v1.3.6" (ticket closed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers plugin is outdated. Do you try [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) plugin?